# Is there a way to know during the run on which parallel branch stage executed?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I got multiple parallel branches job, each branch contains numerous stages.

```
def build_jobs = [:]

build_jobs['1'] = {
    stage ('1A'){}
    stage ('1B'){}
}
        
build_jobs['2'] = {
    stage ('2A'){}
    stage ('2B'){}
}

build_jobs['3'] = {
    stage ('3A'){}
    stage ('3B'){}
}
parallel build_jobs
```

Is there a way to know during the run on which parallel branch stage executed ?

For example:

```
1A -> 1
1C -> 1
2B -> 2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from Jenkins API at `${JENKINS_URL}blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/${JOB_NAME}/runs/${BUILD_ID}/nodes/`. This gets you a JSON that you can iterate over until you meet a stage that has the same name as your `${STAGE_NAME}`.

Here's a little example:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }


    stages {
        stage('doing something') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def build_jobs = [:]

                    build_jobs['1'] = {
                        stage ('1A'){ script { getParent() } }
                        stage ('1B'){}
                    }
        
                    build_jobs['2'] = {
                        stage ('2A'){}
                        stage ('2B'){ script { getParent() } }
                    }

                    build_jobs['3'] = {
                        stage ('3A'){}
                        stage ('3B'){}
                    }
                    parallel build_jobs
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def getParent() {
    def URL = "${JENKINS_URL}blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/${JOB_NAME}/runs/${BUILD_ID}/nodes/"
    def output = sh (returnStdout: true,
        script: "curl -s $URL")
    def parsed_data = readJSON text: output
    
    def my_parent_id = null
    
    for (stage in parsed_data) {
        def displayName = stage.displayName
        if (displayName == env.STAGE_NAME) {
            my_parent_id = stage.firstParent
            break
        }
    }
    
    for (stage in parsed_data) {
        def my_id = stage.id
        if (my_id == my_parent_id) {
            println "FOUND! The stage ${STAGE_NAME} is running under a parent: ${stage.displayName}"
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] }
+ curl -s https://<jenkins>/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/test/runs/3108/nodes/
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
FOUND! The stage 1A is running under a parent: 1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (1B)
+ curl -s https://<jenkins>/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/test/runs/3108/nodes/
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
FOUND! The stage 2B is running under a parent: 2
[Pipeline] }
```